# Could Not Install Ubuntu 16.04 on Lenovo Yoga 3 Pro Due to BusyBox Problem

Tags: boot, 16.04, dual-boot, lenovo

I tried to install Ubuntu 16.04 by booting from USB drive. My laptop allowed me to boot from USB and I selected "install Ubuntu". However, the installation phase stuck at Busy Box v1.22.1. Some web posts say that my hardware is not compatible with the OS. But I have found various posts successfully installed Ubuntu 14.10. Any help would be appreciated.